# How to customize individual category pages in Pelican

Tags: python, html, pelican

I have a website that has an events category page where all articles that are 'events' will be listed. However, I would like to customize the top of this page to include a google calendar. How do I do this in Pelican without it affecting all the other categories?

I tried changing the theme/article_list.html template to have a {% if category == 'events' %} html block but this did not work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: display `category` in HTML and see what you have in this variable.

Comment: it shows me the category name for that page, which on the events page is 'Events', I then capitalized it in {% if category == 'Events' %} and it still doesn't work :/

Comment: `category` can be object which converted to string gives `Events` but compared to string `'Events' ` is not equal. You can try `str(category) == 'Events'`. Or maybe it has some properties like `category.name` - check `pelican` documentation.

Comment: see http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.6.3/themes.html#author-category-tag

Comment: Perfect! using category.name solves it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`category` is object which has property `name` (and [other properties](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.6.3/themes.html#author-category-tag))

```
{% if category.name == 'Events' %}
```